# Attribute Manage Options value add multiple but after save only one display there

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

**Magento 1.7.2 (adminpanel attribute)**

```
TypeError: this.fileValue.toJSON is not a function


$(this.idName+'_save').value = this.fileValue.toJSON();
```

> I have add Attribute drop down option value multiple but after saving
>   data only one value display there. How to get all attribute option
>   list.
>
> **I have added there option**

[image]

> **after save only one value there.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Attribute label option issue generate with Ecommerce Team
SEO Layered Navigation. so i have disable this plugin on this
place on my Project.
```

app/etc/modules

EcommerceTeam_Sln.xml